# Cron expression

Tags: cron

How would I go about writing a Cron expression to trigger every day at 8am and 3:30pm?
I understand how to create an expression to fire once a day, just not at multiple set times.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just use two lines.

```
0 8 * * * command
30 15 * * * command
```

Of course in typical /etc/cron.d format, include the user as arg 6. Expression notation (in all the versions I know of) will get you something other than what you want (e.g. the expressions are additive in nature, so it will run more than you want).

Comment: Thanks Tony, for the record I am using Quartz.net. I created a simple loop and created a trigger for each expression. Nathan

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you need to create Cron Expressions in future using Java Language,
Here is an API available with Verbal Coding style

https://github.com/mabidshafiq/VerbalCronExpression

Example for your scenario is,

```
String exp = ce.cronExp()
    .minuteOfHour("0")
    .hourOfDay("8")
    .everyDay()
    .everyMonth()
    .generate();
```

It will generate  0 8 * * *

and for your understanding

```
* * * * * *
| | | | | | 
| | | | | +-- Year              (range: 1900-3000)
| | | | +---- Day of the Week   (range: 1-7, 1 standing for Monday)
| | | +------ Month of the Year (range: 1-12)
| | +-------- Day of the Month  (range: 1-31)
| +---------- Hour              (range: 0-23)
+------------ Minute            (range: 0-59)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it easy, use once made components- eg. [Crontab generator](http://crontab-generator.org) :o)

Comment: Haha nice one, you can use anchor text for hyperlinks though using: `[anchor text](http://link.com)`. Just an FYI.