# How can we create a cron regular expression for a job to execute at 1am,5:30am,2pm,6pm?

Tags: regex, cron, crontrigger

Regular expression for a job to execute at 1am,5:30am,2pm,6pm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cron expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274359/cron-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need two cronjobs.

[`0 1,14,18 * * * yourJob`](https://crontab.guru/#0_1,14,18_*_*_*)

[`30 5 * * * yourJob`](https://crontab.guru/#30_5_*_*_*)